# iOS: Global constraints for views in different view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have Same UILabel's in different viewcontrollers and I want to make the constraints of them global such that I should be able to edit them in one place and all viewcontrollers will adopt to it. To do that I have done something like this

```
@IBDesignable class TitleLabel: UILabel {
    @IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var BottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topConstraint.constant = 10
        bottomConstraint.constant = 10
        leftConstraint.constant = 20
        rightConstraint.constant = 10
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
 }
```

So each of my label in different view controller is a TitleLabel and I connect its constraints in storyboard and change them in `awakeFromNib()`

Is there a better way then is approach for setting global constraints for same kind of label in different viewcontrollers?

Comment: Seems like you'll use the superview every time to define your constraints, so why don't you define them programmatically? So that you don't even have to add them in your xib/storyboard.

Comment: thanks RomOne it is a good option.May be I should first remove any of the constraints that are set from storyboard and then add new ones. or check if the constraint is active just update its constant

Comment: Ah Yeah that should work! Just a bit worry about unexpected behaviors. If you have a dev who accidentally use that component he may not understand what’s happening as the way it works is a bit unexpected. Maybe make the constraint constant to be ibdesignable, so that the value won’t be hard coded?

Comment: If I just use constraints programmatically, I can't figure out what should be the bottom and top constraints relative to.. For example If I have a TitleLabel which has top spacing to superview but the the bottom constaints relative to another UIView then I can't get the reference of that UIVIew programmatically to add the constraint. For the superview I can just use self.superview...